# How do you enter a variable>variable inequality constraint into a Simplex method calculator?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

In 2-variable linear programming problems, constraints can take the form of either $aX+bY < C$ or $mX > nY$. Both lines graph to form linear bounds so the graphical solution applies. But in 3+ variable problems, you need to use the Simplex method, and the calculators for the Simplex method apparently don't accept constraints of the form $mX > nY$.

I tried converting them algebraically to $mX-nY > 0$, but in a 2 variable problem the Simplex calculator gives me "no solution" when the graphical method finds a solution. Is there another way to enter these sorts of constraints in Simplex calculators?

This the problem I tried:

Maximize: $Z=5x+7y$

$x+y≤30$

$2x+y≤50$

$4x+3y≥60$

$2x≥y$

$x≥0,y≥0$

The graphical method finds that the solution is $x=10, y=20, Z=190$.

I entered that into [the online calculator here](https://linprog.com/en/main-simplex-method) as

$F(x)=5X1+7X2$

$1X1+1X2≤30$

$2X1+1X2≤50$

$4X1+3X2≤60$

$2X1+-1X2≥0$

And it returns:

"Answer:

The system has no solutions or has many solutions."

Comment: You did the right thing by expressing the inequality as $mX-nY>0$. Can you give specific example where this doesn't work?

Comment: Also, could it be that your simplex calculator requires the inequality to be $<$, not $>$? In that case, try $-mX + nY < 0$.

Comment: I added an example problem that I solved graphically but didn't work, with the specific calculator I used. If I invert to $-mX+nY<0$ it does give an answer but it isn't the same one I get graphically . . . $X=(0,20), F(X)=140$ 
Which just makes it even more confusing.

Comment: This calculator did give the correct solution so maybe it was just a calculator problem the whole time? https://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html

Comment: Most likely you made a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You changed $\ge 60$ to $\le 60$, and you also need to specify the $\ge 0$ bounds.  But even with these changes, that online calculator yields the wrong conclusion. The online calculator provides the [complete steps](https://linprog.com/en/main-simplex-method/result;queryParams=%7B%22n%22:6,%22m%22:2,%22max_min%22:1,%22values%22:%5B%5B%221%22,%221%22,%2230%22%5D,%5B%222%22,%221%22,%2250%22%5D,%5B%224%22,%223%22,%2260%22%5D,%5B%222%22,%22-1%22,%220%22%5D,%5B%221%22,%220%22,%220%22%5D,%5B%220%22,%221%22,%220%22%5D%5D,%22function%22:%5B%225%22,%227%22%5D,%22equalSign%22:%5B%222%22,%222%22,%223%22,%223%22,%223%22,%223%22%5D%7D) for the big-M method. After the first step you notice that it has a basis where $x_{10}=-30$, which is not feasible. Apparently it makes an error with the ratio test. The same website has a [dual simplex solver](https://linprog.com/en/main-dual-simplex) which gives the [correct output](https://linprog.com/en/main-dual-simplex/result;queryParams=%7B%22n%22:6,%22m%22:2,%22max_min%22:1,%22values%22:%5B%5B%221%22,%221%22,%2230%22%5D,%5B%222%22,%221%22,%2250%22%5D,%5B%224%22,%223%22,%2260%22%5D,%5B%222%22,%22-1%22,%220%22%5D,%5B%221%22,%220%22,%220%22%5D,%5B%220%22,%221%22,%220%22%5D%5D,%22function%22:%5B%225%22,%227%22%5D,%22equalSign%22:%5B%222%22,%222%22,%223%22,%223%22,%223%22,%223%22%5D%7D).

However, I verified your solution graphically [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tkplfkjhl0).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1496101)

Comment: Usually short answers (in this case related to a typo with significant impact) are better as comments. Otherwise they are sent to review queues.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it is nicer to improve and then upvote an answer than to 'complain'; it's the holiday season, try to be cheerful :)

Comment: @LinAlg: I am not in US, but yes happy Thanksgiving to everyone out there in US and other countries who celebrate this festival. I was not really complaining but just stated that such answers usually arrive in review queues. Also I am happy that this process led to an improvement of the answer and yes a +1 for the answerer.